# json_decode() syntax error on json_last_error_msg() on valid json on php

Tags: php, arrays, json

i have a valid json, i tried decoding with json_decode and this error occoured, "json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in"

however, i use json_last_error_msg and it return syntax error.

see my json below

```
{"id":"96","name":"sample nig. ltd","username":"info@sample.com","password":"cff0e96cbf98af56c230d857858634110385e8a3d1caf76cdf90e29cb1d3f6a6e8e5df85ff20f017593f7443be37d36a8c54ee203a5934e5e125f1ed6c33c771","salt":"kCKErO1VA7ndZ2O7lecPBgRERld5C0JobnZ0cxyT5G03Ug==","email":"","status":"0","office":"control","date":"2019-12-12","position":"control","app":"4","over":"1","edit":"1","deletion":"1","store_id":"0","location_id":"26","client_id":"41","master_status":"1","tm":"07:00:54","update_date":"2019-12-12 07:00:54"}
```

i even reduced my json to get below

```
[{"name":"sample nig. ltd","username":"info@sample.com"}]
```

i need to know whats causing this error. thanks

see my code below

```
public function syncData($url, $data = array()) {
        //$this->arrayPrinter($data);exit;
        $arrayTag = json_encode($data);
        $timeout = 5;
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $arrayTag);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
        $exc = curl_exec($ch);
        $responseCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
        curl_close($ch);
        if ($exc) {
            //$result = json_decode($exc);
            //return ['result' => $exc, 'curlInfo' => $responseCode];
            return $exc;
        } else {
            return ['curlInfo' => $responseCode];
        }
    }



$str = array("syncToken" => $token, 'user_id' => $user, 'client_id' => $client_id, 'location_id' => $location_id, 'table' => $table, "action" => 'user', "column" => '');


$data = $this->syncData("http://localhost/xxxxx_offline/l/server_sync.php", $str);
        $returnData = json_decode($data);
    print_r(json_decode($returnData));

        echo json_last_error_msg();
```

Comment: The json is valid, so may be worth posting your code so we can see how you process it.

Comment: see my code above

Comment: Try `var_dump($data);` to make sure there's no extra hidden characters in the json string.

Comment: dumping data received json, but decoding the json response return such error

Comment: Looks like `syncData()` always returns an array, either `['result' => $exc, 'curlInfo' => $responseCode]` or `['curlInfo' => $responseCode]`

Comment: Please show what the var_dump looks like, so we can try to help.

Comment: var_dump($data) returns [{"name":"sample nig. ltd","username":"info@sample.com"}]"

Comment: Does it say string or array, and what is the length next to it?

Comment: it return null or empty whenever i make use of (json_decode($returnData)), while debugging, json_last_error_msg() returns syntax error

Comment: @aynber, see the response string(572) "[{"name":"sample nig. ltd","username":"info@sample.com"}]"

Comment: If your string is exactly `"[{"name":"sample nig. ltd","username":"info@sample.com"}]"`, and the length is 572, there is something very wrong. There are a lot of hidden characters in there.

Comment: is there anyway to detect or filter hidden character?

Comment: @aynber, any suggestion?